# Triviality of Albanese variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Say I have a variety $X$ over a field $k$ with $\text{Alb}(X)$ trivial, and a fibration in quadrics $f: Y \to X$ (i.e. the fiber above each point of $Y$ is a quadric). Is it true that $\text{Alb}(Y)$ is trivial as well? If so, why?

Comment: The answer should be yes, but I can't give a watertight argument. Here's the idea: consider the Albanese morphism $\alpha_Y : Y \rightarrow \operatorname{Alb}(Y)$. Since every fibre of $f$ is rationally connected, $\alpha_Y$ must map each such fibre to a point. Hence (here's the fishy part) the morphism $\alpha_Y$ should factor through $f$, i.e. we should get an induced morphism $\beta: X \rightarrow \operatorname{Alb}(Y)$ such that $\alpha_Y = \beta \cdot f$. But now since $\operatorname{Alb}(X)$ is trivial, the image of $\beta$ must be a point, hence so too must the image of $\alpha_Y$...

Comment: But then by the universal property, that means $\operatorname{Alb}(Y)$ must be a point. I think the fishy part can be made rigorous by using the so-called MRC fibration of $Y$, but that seems like more machinery than we should need.

Comment: Dear Evariste, unfortunately I don't see how to apply that proposition. There the hypothesis is that we have a morphism of schemes over some base, i.e. a commutative diagram of morphisms. But here that seems to be exactly what we want to prove.